# jquery restart animation after it stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery Continuously Loop Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767286/jquery-continuously-loop-animation)

I want this animation to restart when the div timer reaches 940px.
So far I have this:

```
$('.timer').animate({'width':940}, {queue:false, duration:5000, easing: 'linear'});
if ($('.timer').width() == 940){
    $('.timer').width() == 0;
    $('.timer').animate({'width':940}, {queue:false, duration:5000, easing: 'linear'});
}
```

Comment: Personally I'd do this in CSS: `.timer{animation:expand 5s linear infinite;} @keyframes expand {from{width:0} to{width:940px}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting animated loop:

```
$(".timer").bind("animation.loop", function(){
    $(this).animate({width: 940}, 5000, function(){
        $(this).animate({width: 0}, 5000, function(){
            $(this).trigger("animation.loop");
        });
    });
}).trigger("animation.loop");
```

Do the animation, hard reset, animate again:

```
$(".timer").bind("animation.loop", function(){
    $(this).animate({width: 940, easing: 'linear'}, 5000, function(){
        $(this).css("width", 0).trigger("animation.loop");
    });
}).trigger("animation.loop");
```

Comment: I was looking for it to scale back from zero width like a seamless loop from the same animation.

Comment: Thank you maximkott, but the problem is that I was not looking for it to retract but start from zero equaly like the first time it is animated.

Comment: @user2011284 is that what you mean?

Comment: I think i've got it. but now I can't put the easing: 'linear' to work.
$(".timer").bind("animation.loop", function(){
    $(this).animate({width: 940}, 5000, function(){
 $(this ).css( "width","0" );
        $(this).trigger("animation.loop");
    });
}).trigger("animation.loop");

Comment: @user2011284 I've edited it a bit

Comment: It's exacly that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user2011284 Glad I could help! )) Can you please select the checkmark-sign, on the left of my answer.