# Animation on jQuery only executes one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a funny function that rotates an element 360. The problem is that it only executes the first time and i don't know why!

```
jQuery.fn.circularFun = function() {
            this.stop().animate(
                {rotation: 360},
                {
                  duration: 500,
                  step: function(now, fx) {
                    $(this).css({"transform": "rotate("+now+"deg)"});
                  }
                }
            );
        }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: do you want it to keep rotating

Comment: make your function call itself recursivly

Comment: Look at his. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767286/jquery-continuously-loop-animation

Comment: I don't think he's after continuous, I think the case is just that currently it *can't* be repeated. Say if the rotation is triggered on click, then a second click will do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your first rotation, it will already have been rotated to `360`. You need to set it to `0` after you're finished.

Comment: Or before you start: `this.stop().css('rotation', 0).animate(...)`

Comment: @Alexey: Sure! Same principle.

Comment: Thanks!! That's just what happened!